# What might cause crop and trim to behave differently in different contexts?

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption, crop

I have tried to get a MWE for my problem, but really it is more of a dual to an MWE, because it doesn't work where my actual code DOES work, but I don't understand why it should work. For instance, why would I need to specify negative trim on the right for it to work in a document? Any insights would be appreciated.

First, since, it is a complicated problem, here is what one example EPS image looks like when imported in to GIMP (border added in GIMP for clarity):

[image]

Here are the actual EPS files:

[Yeast](https://app.box.com/s/1cth6n6uf2k5jqkpohb7)

[Human](https://app.box.com/s/qiaar11e3bgfz0q2lrk1)

Here is what I get when I use the same includegraphics parameters in my actual document:

[image]

Here is what the output looks like with the dual MWE (again, same parameters as above):
[image]

And here is the "dual MWE":

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\title{A caption test}
\author{Some one}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}

% 
%This part is copied verbatim from another document where it actually works.
%
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}   % l   b   r   t
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=25cm 3cm -5cm 0cm, clip=true]
    {YeastExpFluxCompare}}
  \vspace{3mm} \caption{Yeast} \label{fig:FluxExpCmp:A}
  \end{subfigure}
&
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=25cm 3cm -5cm 0cm, clip=true]
    {HumanExpFluxCompare}}
  \vspace{3mm} \caption{Human} \label{fig:FluxExpCmp:B}
  \end{subfigure}
\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{fig:FluxExpCmp}
\end{figure}

Please refer to Supporting Table~\ref{fig:FluxExpCmp}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to provide the other MWE too so that users here can compare?

Comment: I will try, but I haven't found how to reproduce it yet.

Comment: Isn't the problem caused by using negative values (`-5cm`) in the `trim` parameter?

Comment: In the example I posted it is, but in my actual large document it looks like I want it to. And I don't understand why.

Comment: After extensively testing code segments, I found out that it was the fact that I was using dvipdfm in one case (the case where it looks right but behaves unexpectedly) and dvipdf in the other case. Is dvipdfm known to behave strangely in this way? I don't think I can use dvipdf for my main document, so that may not be an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arose because, when using dvipdfm(x) I was not specifying:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

and just had

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Previously I thought it was enough to do:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
```